# What's the hex for?

Tags: character-encoding

[image]

I know `0D 0A` means new line,What's `09 09 09 09 09 09 09 3F` ?

It's from UTF-8.

Comment: If you can let us know where this is from maybe we might be able to give a more specific answer as to the purpose of this all.

Answer (score 7):

According to this [ascii table](http://www.cs.utk.edu/~pham/ascii_table.jpg) that is 7 tabs followed by a question mark.

Answer (score 0):

```
09 is TAB
3F is ?
```

So you have 2 newlines, 7 tabs, a question mark and another newline.

Assuming its ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

```
0x09 = 'Horizontal Tab'
0x3F = '?'
```

From [here](http://www.hobbyprojects.com/ascii-table/images/ascii-table1.gif).

Answer (score 0):

an Operating system can use three different kind of numeric bases in order to encode characters. Binary, decimal or hexadecimal encoding. Most of the times the encoding is done using an iso table code ASCII table which for every computer usable characters, defines a binary, decimal and hexadecimal value who would represent it as a number.

You should take a look to man ascii then ;)